# Using JUpgrade migrating to Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, migration, joomla2.5

I am trying to migrate from Joomla 1.6 to 2.5 using JUpgrade.  I find the screen just hangs with the message Checking and Cleaning.  How do I proceed from here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative to upgrading your Joomla 1.6 site.

Firstly, go to the following page and download the file called 
**Joomla_1.6.5_to_1.7.0_Package.zip**.

http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/frs/?action=FrsReleaseBrowse&frs_package_id=5986

Upload this to the root folder for your site and extract it. You will now see that you're running Joomla 1.7

From Joomla 1.7 onwards, the Quick Update was introduced, making updated very easy. So when you go to you're backend, as before, you will see all the quick icons. There will be one that says there is an update for Joomla. Click it and run the process.

Hope this helps